# Parse JSON TV Guide with PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to display the following values from [this](http://www.tvgids.nl/json/lists/programs.php?channels=1) json file.
titel
datum_start
datum_end
I use this code:

```
<?php
$nl1jsonurl='http://www.tvgids.nl/json/lists/programs.php?channels=1';
$nl1jsontext=file_get_contents($nl1jsonurl,true);

$nl1 = json_decode($nl1jsontext);
foreach($nl1->1 as $data)
{
     echo $data->titel . "\n";
     echo $data->datum_start . "\n";
     echo $data->datum_end . "\n";

} 
?>
```

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "db_id": "14612024",
            "titel": "NOS Journaal",
            "genre": "Nieuws/actualiteiten",
            "soort": "",
            "kijkwijzer": "",
            "artikel_id": null,
            "artikel_titel": null,
            "datum_start": "2013-07-05 00:10:00",
            "datum_end": "2013-07-05 00:35:00"
        },
        {
            "db_id": "14642893",
            "titel": "NOS Studio Sportzomer: De Avondetappe",
            "genre": "Sport",
            "soort": "",
            "kijkwijzer": "",
            "artikel_id": "58162",
            "artikel_titel": "Sprinten in Montpellier",
            "datum_start": "2013-07-05 00:35:00",
            "datum_end": "2013-07-05 01:30:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And you question *iiiiis*?

Comment: There's a question mark in there, right on line 2. The question is "php". The answer is yes.

Comment: may be it will give you error about stClass can not convert to string, try this `$nl1 = json_decode($nl1jsontext, true);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This may helps you

```
<?php 
$nl1jsonurl='http://www.tvgids.nl/json/lists/programs.php?channels=1';
$nl1jsontext=file_get_contents($nl1jsonurl,true);

//decode the content lke this
$nl1 = json_decode($nl1jsontext, TRUE);

//print_r($nl1);

foreach($nl1['1'] as $data)
{
     echo $data['title'] . "\n";
     echo $data['datum_start'] . "\n";
     echo $data['datum_end'] . "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your JSON has a property named `1`, you have to access it like so:

```
foreach($nl1->{'1'} as $data)
```

PHP will produce a syntax error if you try to use `$nl1->1`.